# moto z2 play camera2 wrong capabilities?

Tags: android, android-camera2, motorola

Okay, I just got a new Moto z2 play and decided to try and learn the Android Camera2 api using it... The phone is not rooted, and the stock camera app has the option to record slow motion videos and have manual focus during photos... But when I probe the CameraCharacteristics using the Camera2 api, it shows me a LEGACY hardware level device, with no support for high fps recording nor manual sensor control... I've read in the internet that build.prop can be edited so that the device reports the full supported capabilities... But to my understanding, if those capabilities were not supported by default, it wouldn't be possible for stock camera app to show them, right...? So, what's going on? Is there some caveat I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The stock camera app likely has custom interfaces to use those features, built on top of the legacy camera HAL.

Unfortunately, the standard camera2 API cannot run on top of the legacy HAL besides in LEGACY mode, because there's no way to automatically hook into custom OEM additions to the legacy HAL.

So there's likely nothing you can do here to enable these features in your own app; Motorola would have to update their entire camera stack to expose a modern camera HAL for camera2 to work better.

Comment: I have seen a guy that was able to make this phone become a "level 3" hardware device by changing the build.prop... And he reports the phone actually supports most of the features, but they are just disabled by default... Know anything about it?

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't trust it to be at all reliable.  A lot of the chip vendors, who provide the base software for the camera pipelines on manufacturer phones, have built in support for a variety of interface versions.  But a given manufacturer may not have time to ensure it all works fine, and then disable some code paths as a result.  So a build prop may turn it back on, but if it was never tested, especially with the manufacturer additions (and there are always manufacturer additions) stuff may just crash at unexpected places.